# Compile java with tomcat servlet-api.jar using Powershell

Tags: java, powershell, tomcat, servlets, jar

I am currently following this tutorial on tomcat, [Step 6(b) Compiling the Servlet](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html). I was able to compile in cmd, but I want to try to get it to work in Powershell as well.

cmd:

```
javac -cp .;c:\myProject\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java
```

How would I compile using Powershell?

I saw this somewhere, but this isn't compiling the java source file into a class:

```
java -cp '{jar path}' -Dcontext=atest1 -Dresourcepath=." DW_Install
```

I'm fairly novice at powershell, so I don't really understand if I need -Dcontext and -Dresourcepath. What does -D do?

Comment: Get-Help Start-Process, or simpler just proper formatting but I don't have java to test it now

Comment: In your example the latter one isn't compiling, it's running. Therefore you can't really compare them. The `-D` flag is used to pass runtime properties to the program.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman for explaining the -D.

Comment: You might consider using Apache Maven instead of PowerShell.  Maven is a bit of a chore to set up and, it's slow, but you get cross IDE portability and cross platform builds, dependency management, and a lot more.

Comment: I also tried running the project I created using this tutorial with maven in my Java EE Eclipse IDE, but I couldn't get the database to load even after I add the JDBC in the Tomcat lib and as an external jar. I'm still looking into this :P

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem is the semi colon.  In PowerShell, the semi colon is an end of statement character, so the above command will be treated as if it were two separate commands:

```
javac -cp .
c:\myProject\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java
```

To fix this, I imagine you'll need to quote the class path argument:

```
javac -cp '.;c:\myProject\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar' HelloServlet.java
```

Comment: I see, so the semi colon was making Powershell treat it as two separate commands. That makes sense. Thank you so much, now it works in Powershell  too :)